# Can't properly reset value and label of react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a react component with a react-select tag to filter data in a table.
I wanted to clear the value and the label (I mean the text shown in the select element) of select tag when a certain event happens.

So I tried creating a button which triggers resetSelect(), but it doesn't work.
Another issue is that when I choose an option from the select, the label does not change.

```
export default function Filters({ onFilterChange }) {

  const [types, setTypes] = useState([{}]);
  const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(null);

  const fromJsonToOptions = (json) => {
    const options = [
      { label: "all", value: null },
      ...json.map((obj) => ({
        label: obj.name,
        value: obj._id,
      })),
    ];
    return options;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //request to get types to put in select options
    const responseData = response.data;
    const options = fromJsonToOptions(responseData);
    setTypes(options);
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (filterName, filterValue) => {
    if (filterName === "type") {
      setSelectedType(filterValue);
    }
    onFilterChange(filterName, filterValue); //pass data to another component to render the table
  };

  const resetSelect = () => {
    setSelectedType(null);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={types}
          placeholder="all"
          onChange={(selectedOption) => {
            handleFilterChange("type", selectedOption.value);
          }}
          value={selectedType}
        />
        <button onClick={resetSelect}> reset </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value and label of the select tag, you can set the value and defaultValue properties of the select tag to null.

Try this:

```
    export default function Filters({ onFilterChange }) {

  const [types, setTypes] = useState([{}]);
  const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(null);

  const fromJsonToOptions = (json) => {
    const options = [      { label: "all", value: null },      ...json.map((obj) => ({        label: obj.name,        value: obj._id,      })),    ];
    return options;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //request to get types to put in select options
    const responseData = response.data;
    const options = fromJsonToOptions(responseData);
    setTypes(options);
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (filterName, filterValue) => {
    if (filterName === "type") {
      setSelectedType(filterValue);
    }
    onFilterChange(filterName, filterValue); //pass data to another component to render the table
  };

  const resetSelect = () => {
    setSelectedType(null);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={types}
          placeholder="all"
          onChange={(selectedOption) => {
            handleFilterChange("type", selectedOption.value);
          }}
          value={selectedType}
          isClearable={true} // Add this line to enable clearing the select
          defaultValue={null} // Add this line to set the default value to null
        />
        <button onClick={resetSelect}> reset </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, update your `fromJsonToOptions` :

```
const fromJsonToOptions = (json) => {
    const options = [
      { label: "all", value: null },
      ...json.map((obj) => ({
        label: obj.name,
        value: obj._id,
      })),
    ];
    return options;
};
```

Make sure to include the label prop in the Select component as well:

```
<Select
  options={types}
  placeholder="all"
  onChange={(selectedOption) => {
    handleFilterChange("type", selectedOption.value);
  }}
  value={selectedType}
  isClearable={true}
  defaultValue={null}
  label={selectedType ? selectedType.label : ''}
/>
```

Comment: Of course your code works, but I'm using react-select, not the vanilla select tag

Comment: I edtied my answer